# How to automate VMware to switch to multi-monitor mode after startup?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, vmware

How can I automate VMware player 5 to switch to multi-monitor automatically at startup?

I already managed to start it up in full screen.

I tried to shut down the VM when it was in multi-monitor mode and restart it, but it shows me both monitors' screens in a window with scroll bars on one of my monitors. The only way to switch again in real multi-monitor mode is to click on the dual screen icon in the VMware dock bar.

Is there a way to automate this action?

Comment: You mean the *guest* is supposed to switch to multi-monitor mode?

Comment: That what i want it to do. Yes. When i start my Vm I want it to automaticaly switch to dual monitor mode whitout any user action. My guest is an windows XP configured to extend desktop to both monitors.